# 'The thread with which I used to tie her hair tight' or 'The thread in which I used to tie her hair tight'?

Tags: grammar

In this two sentences which one is better?
Also, tight has to be at the end of the sentence because it is part of a poem.

Comment: It's a poem, so grammar doesn't matter. But neither *with which* nor *in which* is idiomatic. Simply remove those two words: *the thread I used*.

Comment: @Jason: when you do that, you change the meaning from *used to* (something I habitually did in the past) to *used* (made use of). And you change the meter, which may also be a consideration.

Comment: How are you using the words 'used to'? Are you saying you used the thread to do it, or are you saying you used to tie her hair but now you don't?

Comment: For the word "used" is this referring to an action taken in the past? Or you using the thread to tie her hair? That would change any answer. Either way, grammar does not matter as much when you are writing stylistically.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Yes, I am saying that I used to tie her hair but don't anymore.

Comment: @CecilyJansen Here "Used" is referring to an action taken in the past.

Comment: OK. In that case the first sentence is better. The line sounds a little awkward though. "With which" is perfect grammar, but most people would tend to break the rules and say, "The thread I used to tie your hair with." If you *want* to be grammatically perfect and use '"with which", you should probably also use the word "tightly" instead of tight. Most of us do say "tie it tight" when speaking informally, but not in the same sentence as "with which", which is formal. In other words, there is a change of *register*, and it makes the line feel somewhat awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "in which" is idiomatic in this semantic context; an ngram shows that it is never found ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&smoothing=3&content=thread+in+which+to+tie%2Cthread+with+which+to+tie&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthread%20with%20which%20to%20tie%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthread%20with%20which%20to%20tie%3B%2Cc0)) for the basic form, whereas "with which" is. It is safer to use this latter.

Comment: They're both idiomatic; they mean slightly different things. See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=hair+tied+in+a+ribbon%2C+hair+tied+with+a+ribbon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chair%20tied%20in%20a%20ribbon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chair%20tied%20with%20a%20ribbon%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor A ribbon might be conceived as a loop, although that's streching concepts a bit far. However a thread is not a loop of thread and for "thread" the ngram shows no such option in the case of "tie with/in a thread" I still wouldn't write "tied in a thread". You are right as far as the existence but I think the minority is quite off: [with-in](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&smoothing=3&content=tied+in+a+thread%2Ctied+with+a+thread&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctied%20in%20a%20thread%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctied%20with%20a%20thread%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I don't believe anybody would use *hair tied in a ribbon* to mean *hair tied in a loop.*

Comment: @PeterShor How can you keep hair together if some sort of tie does not go around it and so doing has the shape of a loop?

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by *loop*. But nobody ties their hair with a *thread*; this is poetic license, and presumably means some kind of ribbon or similar stuff. So I think *in* works here.

Answer (score 0):

They're both grammatical.

I would use *in which*, because

> the thread with which I used to tie her hair tight,

sounds too much like

> the thread which I used to tied her hair tight,

which means that people could get confused as to the meaning. (In fact, if you look at the comments, people are getting confused by this.)

Comment: Note that I didn't downvote. I think that you change the meaning of the verb from "past habit" to "utilising".

Comment: You used to tie her hair tight while somehow being inside a thread??